# Iphone 6 is not on iphone find but i have registered it with icloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

Help!! I have miss placed my iphone 6. I have also registered the IME number on icloud. When i log into iphone find the phone is not as one of my devices. 
How do i find the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Find My Phone in the iCloud settings on the device that you want to track before. If it's disabled there you won't be able to track it using FMI.